# How to fix CORS origin issue in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am writing below code to download .CSV file from other domain.

```
      const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

      let url = 'http://example.com' + data.filepath;
      console.log(url);

      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'Sample.csv').then((entry) => {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

       }, (error) => {
          console.log("No file to download");

       });
```

It's giving me below error

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/sample.csv (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is a security feature of browser,  that you can prevent from the URLs server. Anyways that issue won't be seen on mobile devices,  when you install the application after build.

Comment: I am using 'ionic-view' app to test 'MyApp' on device, but when I click on download button nothing happens. No file getting downloaded.